# Why is matlab's mldivide so much better than dgels?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, lapack, intel-mkl

Solve `Ax = b`.  Real double.  `A` is overdetermined Mx2 with M >> 2.  `b` is Mx1.  I've run a ton of data against `mldivide`, and the results are excellent.  I wrote a mex routine with MKL `LAPACKE_dgels` and it's nowhere near as good.  The results have a ton of noise and the underlying signal is barely there.  I checked the routine against the MKL example results first.  I've searched through the `mldivide` doc (flowchart) and the SO questions.  All I found is Matlab uses QR factorization for overdetermined rectangular.

What should I try next?  Am I using the wrong LAPACK routine?  Please help guide me in the right direction.

**Update:**
To within E-15 floating point difference on the solution vector, Intel MKL LAPACKE_dgels has the same result as Matlab mldivide for real double overdetermined (rectangular) problems.  As far as I can tell, this is the QR method used.

Beware the residuals returned from this dgels.  They do not equate to b - Ax.  Many of them are close to this value, whereas some are far from it.

Comment: For us to check if you are using the function the wrong way, you'd better provide a minimum working example (even if with small matrices the issue is not reproduced).

Comment: As an alternative, give a try to LAPACK's [DGELSY()](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/d4b/dgelsy_8f_source.html). It also makes use of QR decomposition to solve overdetermined systems. Finally, give a try to [DGELSD()](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d6a/dgelsd_8f_source.html) if the matrix A is ill conditionned. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637108/the-difference-between-c-lapack-sgels-and-python-numpy-lstsq-results/41642797#41642797 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55367024/fastest-way-of-solving-linear-least-squares/55483480#55483480

Comment: @francis. Thank you, that's good advice. I read Armadillo uses QR then falls back to SVD (dgelsd) if its ill conditioned. But the int info return parameter of dgels is never positive (always zero).

Comment: Indeed, the file `include/armadillo_bits/glue_solve_meat.hpp` describes a call to `status = auxlib::solve_approx_fast()` and a call to `auxlib::solve_approx_svd()` if status is false. `solve_approx_fast()` calls `lapack::gels` and `auxlib::solve_approx_svd()` calls `lapack::gelsd()`. The return parameter of dgels become positive if a null pivot is found, thus preventing the system from being solved. The fact that it is always zero is consistent with a good conditioning of your matrix. Congratulations for having solved your problem yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was not the solution `x`, rather the returned residuals from `DGELS`.  This routine's outputs are modify-in-place on the input array pointers.  The [MKL doc](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521112) says the input array `b` is overwritten with the output vector `x` for the first `N` rows, then the residuals in `N+1` to `M`.  I confirmed this with my code.

The mistake was in aligning the `b[N+1]` residuals to original inputs `b[1]`, and making further algorithmic decisions on that.  The correct alignment of residual to original input is `b[1]` to `b[1]`.  The first `N` residuals are not available; you have to compute those afterwards.

The doc doesn't say they are residuals per se, rather specifically

> the residual sum of squares for the solution in each column is given by the sum of squares of modulus of elements `n+1` to `m` in that column.